# What is the best way to implement notification in a C# web application?

Tags: c#, notifications

What is the best way to implement notification in a C# web application?   If this was an EAI BPEL application, I would be using the notification feature within the BPEL specifications to emit events at key tasks I want to monitor.  Since this is a C# web application, what are the architectural options?   Should I drop messages via pub/sub using NServiceBus at points I want to monitor or should I use .Net event handling to attach to methods I care about or a mixture of both or is there an option I'm not aware of.   The case I'm trying to optimize is the least amount of code with the maximum flexibility and scalability.

Comment: May be MS SignalR? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR

Answer (score -1):

The event aggregator pattern is a great one to use for things like this:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html

You can check out the kigg project:

http://kigg.codeplex.com/

It has a pretty decent implementation. I think they could improve it a little but overall I like it.

Comment: Would you back up the eventHander with NServiceBus?

Comment: @Albert to be honest I had never heard of nservicebus before but it looks good. But I wouldn't be able to comment intelligently about whether to use it or not.

Comment: It's a way to do publish/subscribe using MQ based messaging.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what the workflow would be from start to finish?